# C# : how to read a json file with object as value

Tags: c#, json, game-development

In my C# program I have a json file which I'm trying to read using Newtonsoft library. The issue is that some values of the file are object, and it's giving me difficulties with trying to deserializing it.

My json file has this shape :

```
{
  "frames": {
    "0": {
      "frame": { "x": 0, "y": 0, "w": 40, "h": 40 },
      "duration": 300
    },
    "1": {
      "frame": { "x": 0, "y": 0, "w": 40, "h": 40 },
      "duration": 300
    },
    "2": {
      "frame": { "x": 0, "y": 0, "w": 40, "h": 40 },
      "duration": 300
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my code to catch json file data :

```
String framesDataJson = File.ReadAllText(@"Content/simple.json");

Dictionary<string, object> jsonFramesData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(framesDataJson);

Console.WriteLine(jsonFramesData["frames"]["0"]);
```

With that, I was able to retrieve the file correctly but when I try to access the value of the "0" key, I have the following error :

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'CS0021'

I know that using `object` in `Dictionary<string, object>` is not the right way and this is what's causing the problem, but I don't know how to do it another way.

The ideal for me would be to be able to bind the value to the fields of my `AnimationFrame` class as Newtonsoft allow to do [that](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm).

The `AnimationFrame` class is the following :

```
public class AnimationFrame
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> frame { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Visual Studio will create classes to match your JSON.  Edit Menu / Paste Special / Paste JSON as Classes

Comment: I'm using vscode, not visual studio

Comment: `dynamic jsonFramesData = JObject.Parse(framesDataJson);` `Console.WriteLine(jsonFramesData.frames["0"]);`

Comment: There are several online tools to create concrete classes for your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

create classes that as same the structure of your JSON file. Specifically, create a `FrameDetails` class for the inner objects and a `FramesData` class for the entire file structure .

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Read the JSON file
            string framesDataJson = File.ReadAllText(@"Content/simple.json");

            // Deserialize the JSON string into the FramesData object
            FramesData jsonFramesData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FramesData>(framesDataJson);

            // Accessing and displaying the frame details
            foreach (var frameEntry in jsonFramesData.frames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Frame {frameEntry.Key}:");
                Console.WriteLine($" Duration: {frameEntry.Value.duration}");
                Console.WriteLine($" X: {frameEntry.Value.frame["x"]}");
                Console.WriteLine($" Y: {frameEntry.Value.frame["y"]}");
                Console.WriteLine($" W: {frameEntry.Value.frame["w"]}");
                Console.WriteLine($" H: {frameEntry.Value.frame["h"]}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class FrameDetails
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> frame { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
}

public class FramesData
{
    public Dictionary<string, FrameDetails> frames { get; set; }
}
```